# Watir-webdriver:How to read tooltip text

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing a script to set verify tool-tip for label control. I am using

`$browser.label(:text,"Help").hover
$browser.text.include?("Hint Text").should == true`

When I execute this, tool tip is displayed on browser, but I am not able to assert the tool-tip.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share the html? There are a variety of ways that the tooltip could be implemented,  each requiring a different solution.

Comment: Tool tip is implemented using title attribute in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the title attribute of an element using the `title` method.

Assuming that the element is:

```
<label title="Hint Text">Help</label>
```

You can get the title attribute value:

```
$browser.label(:text => "Help").title
#=> "Hint Text"
```

Or as a validation in a test:

```
$browser.label(:text => "Help").title.should eq("Hint Text")
```

Note that you do not need to hover over the element to check its title attribute.